# Do all Sturm- Liouville problems with singular boundary conditions have infinitely many Eigenvalues?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

I know it is the case if the boundary conditions are regular and unmixed, but what about the singular case?

Also what is meant by L being regular? Does it mean the boundary conditions are regular?